# How does one get a program to print with a printer in java

Tags: java, printing

How do you get a program to print with a printer in java?

I'm trying to get together a board game for my friends and I to play but the mechanics of it requires that a new deck of cards be created for every game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the Java printing API of course:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/printing/index.html